# How to display the value within the column only and display it (PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the value of that row within the column and display it. I don't want to display the whole row, just the value inside the column. Also I don't want to display all the array value at the same time. I just want to get the specific value within row of the column at a time using loop. [Here is the value that I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfRe9.png)

Here's the code too.

```
<?php 
    include('../../private/includes/dbh.php');
    $mod_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id from moderator");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($mod_result)){
?>

<input type="text" name="moderator_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

<?php
    }
?>
```

UPDATE: Here is the output of changing the mysqli_fetch_row into mysqli_fetch_assoc and mysqli_fetch_array. [Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdgLf.png)

Comment: what is the result from your script?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What you have looks like it would work - what is your script currently outputting? Inside the `while` loop, if you do `var_dump($row);` what is output?

Comment: I posted an answer, kindly look at it. Thank you.

Comment: Your suggestion works, but its outputting all the values in the columns. What I want to I achieve is that to display the current id of the logged in moderator and display it in the form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So since you already have the moderator logged in in your webpage, you already have an identifier for this moderator, so seen your table if you have the user name you can just populate the variable with that value and make the query fetch the correspondent value

```
$moderator = 'June';
```

So the query will be:

```
SELECT id FROM moderator WHERE mod_username='$moderator'
```

You just need to determine what value you can use it from the logged user, maybe even if you have access to the id, you dont need to make another database call.

```
<?php 
    include('../../private/includes/dbh.php');
    $mod_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM moderator WHERE mod_username='$moderator'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mod_result)){
?>

<input type="text" name="moderator_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

<?php
    }
?>
```

I hope this resolves it.

Comment: it's displaying the output, but the problem now is it's display all the output in the columns. I just want the logged in moderator id and display that logged in moderator id in the form.

Comment: @RavLucin then you should change the query. select row from moderator table where the moderator id is equal to the currently logged in moderator. and so on. use a `WHERE` clause

Comment: Ah! i didnt understand your question then! So add WHERE clause to the query SELECT id FROM moderator WHERE id='$moderator_id'

Comment: I added the query you guys suggested, now it's outputting  "Undefined variable: moderator_id"

Comment: <?php 
                    include('../../private/includes/dbh.php');
                    $mod_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id from moderator WHERE id = '$moderator_id'");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mod_result)){
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="moderator_id" value="<?php echo $moderator_id ?>">
                <?php
                    }
                ?>

Comment: You must make a variable with the number of moderator you want to display, I only write $moderator_id as an example where you can change for your variable name.

Comment: Your solutions works temporarily, but I want the webpage to know which moderator is logged in and get their user ID. Declaring the name directly of the moderator in the code won't work if there are more moderators. I would have to manually type their names if this is the case. Thank you for your answer anyways, this gave me an idea now how to modify the code.

Comment: This is only an example of how you can implement the database call, but in the real world, you don't want to hardcode the username to find the id... so as @WOUNDEDStevenJones pointed... you need to figure how you get the moderator logged in, and if theres a PHP session or a cookie containing that information, so you can use it to populate the variable $moderator. But as I don't know that based on the information you provide I can only show you the direction you must follow to resolve it.  Happy to help if you provide more info like the available user variables you have or the login method.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your loop to use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead of [`mysqli_fetch_row`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), then you should be able to reference `$row['id']`.

From the PHP documentation:

`mysqli_fetch_row($mod_result)` - "Get a result row as an enumerated array". `$row[0]` is how you'd reference the first column.

`mysqli_fetch_assoc($mod_result);` - "Fetch a result row as an associative array". `$row['id']` will return the value of the `id` column in this row.

```
<?php 
    include('../../private/includes/dbh.php');
    $mod_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id from moderator");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mod_result)){
?>

<input type="text" name="moderator_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: It shows the output, but it's displaying all the values in the column. What I want to achieve is to get the id of the current logged in moderator and display that id in the form.

Comment: string(1) "3" } "> 
array(1) {  [
 string(1) "4" } "> 
array(1) {  [
 string(1) "5" } ">

Comment: I just saw your other comment about a moderator ID. Do you have that value as a PHP variable anywhere? You'll need to modify your MySQL query to account for that, because right now you're selecting _all_ `ID`s from the `moderator` table. This also explains why your `while` loop is iterating multiple times, and why you're getting multiple `<input>`s while you're only expecting 1.

Comment: The variable isn't declared anywhere, that's why I'm confused where to put it, I can't assign a variable if I do not know what I'm gonna declare it with. But yea what you said makes sense. Now I just want the Id of the logged in user and display that output.

Comment: How is a moderator logged in? In order to be logged in there needs to be some sort of session ID that you can reference or is saved in the user's browser and/or your server. Do you have more code to display this page or is it only these ~10 lines? Are you using any sort of PHP framework or building this from scratch? Do you have functionality to log in right now?

Comment: Everything functions according to what I expect, but to sum it up the reason why I want to put the id of moderator to the form is because, when I create a user I want to know which moderator that user belongs to. So know when I create a user in the form I want that moderator id to go along with it to the database table of the client. This way I can track which client it belongs to.

Comment: Is the moderator adding the client? If so, then the moderator must be logged in and you must know their ID from the `moderator` table, right? I think you don't necessarily even need to query your database again because you're just wanting to output the _current moderator's ID_, which you should already have access to in PHP if they're logged in.

Comment: I think this makes sense, If I were a moderator using the website and I know my id, i could type my id manually to the form. This could in practical use solve the problem. I guess I just wanted to make everything automatic whenever I create a new client the id of the current logged in moderator is automatically inputted in the form. I could just use the <input type="hidden"> and not <input type="text">

Comment: You're missing my point. If a user _is already logged in to your site_, then their browser has to have some sort of session cookie stored. That session cookie will align with some sort of `login` table in your database, so you'll be able to look up their ID based on their session ID. It's how (most) logins work on the web. I suggest you create a new question with more information about how your site works (login functionality specifically) so you can figure out how to get the current user's ID.